C++ QT Copying the objects of a QList<obj *> to another QList<obj *>
I have a QList like this
QList<media *> MyList;
Where media is an abstract class created by me. I use this list to store objects of tree different classes, all tree inherit from media. I have to keep them all in one singular list.
Now I also have a method like:
void copyListOfMedia(QList<media *> listToCopy)
The final result has to be that MyList contains the pointers of objects that are a COPY of the objects pointed by listToCopy.
Now my first idea was to do something like this:
void copyListOfMedia(QList<media *> listToCopy)
{
    for(int i=0; i<listToCopy.size(); i++)
    {
        MyList.append(new media(*(listToCopy[i])));
    }
}

But it's not correct because it's allocating an object of abstract class.
So what do you think is the best idea to solve this?
Pls, if you find some better solutions to manage the hole thing I wold accept all the suggestions, since I am new using QT and c++ in general.
At the beginning I thought the solution might be to redefine the copy constructor of the class media (it does not contain any pointer, so I've not done it yet couse I didn't thought it would be a necessity). But also I don't think that's the solution couse it's still trying to allocate an object of abstract class.
Another solution might be creating a visitor class to separate the copying process; but at the end all the objects have to be in the same list and I have no idea how to implement this.

The usual solution is to give media a method like virtual media* Clone() = 0;, and have derived classes override it and create copies of themselves (could be as simple as return new Derived(*this);)

Alternatively, since the classes are known and there are only three of them, you could consider a simple if/switch block that creates the new object based on the current type.

If you already have the Visitor pattern set up, then indeed it shouldn't be difficult to implement a visitor that creates a copy of the concrete class it visits.
